# Order of integration can be swapped if limits are constants, right?

Tags: calculus, integration, multiple-integral

The order of integration can be easily swapped if the limits are constants, right?
$$\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d}f(x,y)dydx=\int_{c}^{d}\int_{a}^{b}f(x,y)dxdy$$
It only gets computationally hard if the limits are functions of each other, right?
$$\int_{a}^{b}\int_{c(x)}^{d(x)}f(x,y)dydx \neq \int_{c(x)}^{d(x)}\int_{a}^{b}f(x,y)dxdy$$
Sorry for the potentially trivial answer. Just doing a reality check over here.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: When the limits are not constant, it's not just hard, it's impossible to change the order of integration (without changing the variables, and even then it's not always possible).

Comment: The integrals in your second expression are not just different, they are different objects as well - the left one is a constant, the right one is a function of $x$

Comment: @YuriyS Im not a mathematician. Although the notation is obviously wrong. I believe it also conveys the intended idea fairly intuitively also (as opposed to a more rigorous but convoluted one)

Comment: @Alan, the notation is fine (expression on the right hand side makes sense, but good manners suggest that you use another variable for the limits, like $\int_{c(t)}^{d(t)}$). Not in your post, obviously, but in the general sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is true in a very general sense, by Fubini's theorem.
In $\mathbb{R}^2$, the conditions for Fubini's theorem boil down to:

> The integral of the absolute value over the specified range must be finite, in any one of the three senses that:
>
> - we integrate with respect to $x$ and then $y$
> - we integrate with respect to $y$ and then $x$
> - we integrate simultaneously over the entire surface
>
> If this holds, then the values of all three of the above integrals are equal.

This is usually true over a compact (i.e. bounded and closed) range, because we're usually integrating continuous functions over those ranges, and continuous functions on compact sets are necessarily bounded in modulus.

Comment: Quick side question, can it be said that Fubini's theorem is essentially the foundation upon which the common iterated integral is based?

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Tonelli's theorem is very closely related; you might see my answer referred to as the Fubini-Tonelli theorem.